# INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY response for the sell amount when calling the Polygon API

Tags: polygon, 0x

When trying to make an api call to Ox through Polygon, I am receiving the following error:

`{ "code": 100, "reason": "Validation Failed", "validationErrors": [ { "field": "sellAmount", "code": 1004, "reason": "INSUFFICIENT_ASSET_LIQUIDITY" } ] }`

The API call is:

`https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010&buyToken=0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619&sellAmount=1000000000000000000`

I have tried with more zeros and less zeros as the sell amount and nothing seems to work. Anyone had any luck with this call on Polygon. I have been able to use it with AVAX no problem...

Answer (score 1):

Since you API query passes the address of the chain's native token (MATIC), the value for the token's address needs to be `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`. We always list a chain's native token address at [/swap/v1/tokens](https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/tokens).

This API call returns successfully:

`https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee&buyToken=0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619&sellAmount=1000000000000000000`